# What does a "!" after a parenthesis call do?

Tags: typescript

I just noticed something I've never seen in almost a decade of JS programming.

```
const field: IntrospectionField = (resource.type as IntrospectionObjectType).fields.find(
  field => {
    return field.name === key;
  }
)!; // HERE
```

Note the `!` at the end of the last line.

I wonder:

- What it is supposed to do?
- What does it actually do?

> I believe it's just a typo, and that it doesn't affect anything, but I could be wrong.

I've found this in an open source piece of software at https://github.com/Weakky/ra-data-opencrud/blob/master/src/getResponseParser.ts#L17

Comment: Not a typo, here, it asserts that the `.find` returns something (and not `undefined`)

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! I hadn't thought it could be a TS-specific notation. It makes more sense now. Also, it's wrong because this particular call can actually yield `null` values, but that's another story. Thanks!

Comment: Don't quite understand the reason for downvoting though, especially without any explanation...

Comment: You've got an upvote 

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'm not that surprised given that the answer looks to be [trivial to find](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+exclamation+mark) via a search engine

Comment: Trivial to find when you figure out it's TS-related ;) I assumed that was some JS weird stuff at first